# Change Consecutive Row Value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query, subquery

I am trying to change value of Consecutive AA to first AA as AA1 and second one as AA2, if only one AA then it should be as AA1, its possible to change all AA to AA1 and then search for 2nd consecutive AA1 to change it AA2
example

[image]

Comment: "I want" isn't a description of a **specific** issue or question you encountered while **you** made an attempt, with reasonable effort, to solve a problem. So [edit] the question and show what you have tried and explain exactly where you have what issue with it.

Comment: I tried a lot in my own and stuck in a similar condition, I can't show you my exact approach but I can explain that I am stuck in similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `[Name]` column is unique, and that's the field you want to sort on (since a table is unsorted by default) this query using the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) **window function** should do the `UPDATE` you're looking for:

```
WITH CTE_NewDept AS
(
    SELECT 
        [Name], 
        Dept + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Dept ORDER BY [Name]) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Dept, -- Generates a unique ID for each row within a Dept ordered by the [Name]
        COUNT([Name]) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept) AS DeptCount -- Counts how many dupe Dept there are for each type of Dept (used to filter out non-dupes in the UPDATE statement below)
    FROM Table1
)

UPDATE T
SET T.Dept = N.Dept
FROM Table1 AS T
INNER JOIN CTE_NewDept AS N
    ON T.[Name] = N.[Name]
WHERE N.DeptCount > 1 -- Only update Dept that are dupes
```

Comment: Its not like that, we can't sort or order by any other column

Comment: @AvinashKumar If you can't sort on any column then how do you define what row is first? (A table has no order to it without using an `ORDER BY` clause.)

Comment: that is what I need to figure it out to find which one is first, somewhere it suggested to use cursor but I am unable to find it. If I use order by then third consecutive will get affected, where only 2nd consecutive need to change. that is my point

Comment: @AvinashKumar Sorry your example is not clear enough, if you could update your post to clarify why your outputted results go "AA1", "AA1", and then "AA2" instead of "AA1", "AA2", "AA3" (for rows A, D, E) that would be helpful. But regardless, if you're not allowed to order by any of the columns, then it's impossible to know which one is first (unless you were already using one of SQL Server's **Auditing** or **Logging** features, but you would've had to explicitly enable them). A cursor won't help you figure out which one is first.